# List view search filter in jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list view in html which has headers and child elements. I have implemented jquery script to filter the header and child elements, but the problem is when I search the child elements, I get that specific child element with other elements in it also. The actual result should be (**suppose I search "xxx" in the searchbox, the output should be the header element and the child-xxx element only which is not happening**). I get the xxx result with other child element-aaa also. Please help. I have attached the jsfiddle link  "[My Test Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gS4AS/)"

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){    
var SEARCHWORD = this.value;
$("#list li").each(function(){
if($(this).              
          text().toUpperCase().
          indexOf(SEARCHWORD.toUpperCase()) >=0)
   $(this).show();
else
   $(this).hide();

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#search").keyup(function () {
   var SEARCHWORD = this.value;
   $("#list li").each(function () {
      $(this).hide();
      $('p:contains(' + SEARCHWORD + ')').closest('li').show();
      $('p:contains(' + SEARCHWORD + ')').show().siblings('p').hide();
      if (SEARCHWORD == "") {
          $('#list').find('p:hidden').show();
      }
   });
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gS4AS/1/)

---

You have to add this condition to show back the hidden elems:

```
if (SEARCHWORD == "") {
   $('#list').find('p:hidden').show();
}
```

#### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gS4AS/5/)

---

As per your latest dom structure with tables and tds update to this code:

```
$("#search").keyup(function () {
  var SEARCHWORD = this.value;
  $("#list tr").each(function () {
      $(this).hide();
      $('td:contains(' + SEARCHWORD + ')').closest('tr').show();
      if (SEARCHWORD == "") {
          $('#list').find('tr:hidden').show();
      }
   });
});
```

#### [Updated Fiddle with table structure.](http://jsfiddle.net/gS4AS/6/)

Comment: Thanks Jai, I have tried you fiddle, its working fine but when i clear the text, only the header shows up neglecting the child elements, could you please check this.

Comment: Hi Jai, instead of <p> tag , i have the table tag containing values, ie <ul id='list'>
    <li id='a1'>
         <h3>Header1</h3>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>this is aaa
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>this is xxx
                </td>
            </tr>
            <table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>this is def</td>
            </tr>
                </table>
    </li>

Comment: Could ypu please help me with searching of this table values in the same way as you did for the <p> , Am new to this jquery, your help will be be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your fiddle to include a combination of CSS and JS to accomplish what you want.  One of your complications is that you want the header to show if any of the siblings match.  So you cannot hide the header based on a non-match because there may be a different sibling match.

Second is that multiple siblings could potentially match. This means you can't just show/hide siblings based on a match.  If both siblings match you need to show both, and any code that hides siblings could potentially hide a previous match.

I've added CSS code to do the showing/hiding based on matches and the event that the user is searching something (so clearing the box will reshow everything).  Then the JS just sets or removes the 'hit' class.

```
#list.searching h3, #list.searching li > p { display: none }
#list.searching li > p.hit, #list.searching li.hit h3 { display: block }
```

The JS

```
var theList = $('#list');
$("#search").keyup(function(){    
  var SEARCHWORD = this.value;
   // remove all hits each time
  theList.find('.hit').removeClass('hit');
  if (SEARCHWORD) { 
    // if a search term make sure the list is marked
    theList.addClass('searching');
 } else {
    // remove searching mark
    theList.removeClass('searching'); 
  }
  $("#list li p").each(function() {
    // case-insensitive matching
    if (this.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(SEARCHWORD.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        $(this).addClass('hit').parent().addClass('hit');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('hit');
    }
  })
});
```

Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gS4AS/4/

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the reply, but when i run your updated fiddle, the search is not showing up any list, it goes blank, Could you please check this.